# Error returned when trying to login to Stack Overflow Teams after adding another login

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts, stack-overflow-for-teams

I was successfully logged in to our new company Stack Overflow Teams account using email + password. I then (foolishly) attempted to attach another login using GitHub, thinking I could have my personal account linked with my Teams account.

Now when I attempt to login to the Teams account using email and password, I receive a 500 error and the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page.

[image]

Since my email address is a [G Suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Workspace) account, I attempted to log in via Google [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) instead, but it also fails, this time with *There was an error fetching your account from Google. Please try logging in again*. Logging in with the GitHub account just takes me to an empty Teams account.

The account is quite new, so the worst case scenario is I just ask my boss to delete and recreate the account, but is there is a way to resolve the issue instead?

Comment: Please [submit a support request](https://stackenterprise.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/new?type=teams) so that your account can be fixed. You won't be able to resolve this problem on Meta.

Comment: Thanks @animuson, I have sent through a support request.